# If value of specific cell change then clear contents from that row only from which cell value change

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to build a code where, if there is change in cell then clear contents from that row only where value of cell changed.
here is my code,

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     Dim KeyCells As Range

     Set KeyCells = Range("I1:I209")

     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
     Is Nothing Then

     If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE, YOU WANT TO DELETE?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
       'WHAT SHOULD BE CODE TO DELETE CONTENTS FROM THAT ROW FROM WHICH CELL VALUE CHANGED
     End If

    End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here I want to clear contents from specific range from that row only, I don't want to clear whole row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EntireRow` property of `Range` object to get `Target` row range:

```
 Target.EntireRow.ClearContents
```

while to clear only changed cells:

```
Target.ClearContents
```

and if you want to clear cells in columns B to, J to M and Q to S in same row as changed cell, then:

```
Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Range("B:D, J:M ,Q:S")).ClearContents
```

in all cases you should treat the above codes as Jeeped showed in his answer, i.e.:

- make sure the clearing doesn't trig `Worksheet_Change` event in infinite loop by enclosing the clearing code beteeen `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`
- make sure any possible error doesn't prevent form reaching `Application.EnableEvents = True` statement, by placing an `On Error GoTo safe_exit` statement before `Application.EnableEvents = False` and moving `Application.EnableEvents = True` right after a `safe_exit:` statement

Comment: For example If change in cell value of suppose I4 then clear contents from cell range B4:D4,J4:M4,Q4:S4

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer solved your question, you may consider marking the answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: @MR.PATEL, I see you marked another answer as the solution. What’s the point?

Comment: @MR.PATEL, any feedback?

Comment: seems like my _allocated time_ isn't so _valuable_ to you as some other people one seems to be...

Comment: No bro, it actully helped me a lot and I also mention thank you for that. and If you feel hurt by me than I appologize for that.

Comment: Again I do repeat thank you for your attention, giving your time as well as putting efforts and sharing knowledge for solving problem. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Not Intersect(Range("I1:I209"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE, YOU WANT TO DELETE?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) <> vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            On Error GoTo safe_exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim t As Range
            For Each t In Intersect(Range("I1:I209"), Target)
                intersect(range("B:D,J:M,Q:S"), t.EntireRow).ClearContents
            Next t
     End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = true

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for help. i do appriciate your help, but i would like to clear specific cells from that range not whole row